# Suspending SwingWorker execution until a Component has stopped being resized

Tags: swing, repaint

I'm using repaint to trigger a `SwingWorker`. This worker automatically recreates an image to fit the width of the enclosing `JPanel` according to an autofit option in an application.

The issue is that is causing an Out of Memory Exception. This is because the images have a big resolution and the worker is being called continuously when the window is being drag-resized.

What I've tried to avoid this is only `execute()` when `isDone()` is true. However I feel there is a better way of doing this. Perhaps by using some sort of timer? What do you suggest?

Comment: I doubt, about what I be suggesting will work or not. Though you can try that, you can add one [HierarchyBoundsListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyBoundsListener.html) to your `JPanel`, and inside the `ancestorResized(...)` you can write, `swingWorkerObject.cancel(true);swingWorkerObject.execute();`, that might will give a feeling of restarting it, not sure though how good the solution is !!!!

Comment: +1, for more ATTENTION, for someone who can help, if mine never worked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little left field, but basically what I do is use a javax.swing.Timer.  The basic idea is to only perform an action when the timer fires.

```
private Timer timer;

.
.
.

timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // Perform required action
        // Start the swing worker ??

    }
});
timer.setCoalesce(true);
timer.setRepeats(false);

.
.
.

public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {

    // Force the time to start/reset
    timer.restart();

    super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

}
```